# ASP.NET ActionLink specifying controller as a string parameter

Tags: asp.net, routes

I have this route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
  name: "Task",
  url: "Projects/{projectID}/Tasks/{action}/{id}",
  defaults: new { controller = "Tasks", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Wanted to create a link with:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Add task", "Create", "Tasks", new { projectID = 5 })
```

but I get (I'm in the projects index view):

```
http://localhost:25814/Projects/Create?Length=5
```

When I use

```
@Html.ActionLink("Add task", "Create", new { controller = "Tasks", projectID = 5 })
```

I get the correct url:

```
http://localhost:25814/Projects/5/Tasks/Create
```

I don't understand why the difference... The helper method with this signature:

```
(string linkText, string actionName, string controllerName, object routeValues)
```

exists! So why cannot I use the simpler method?

Comment: No such overload exists.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink

Comment: Thanx! I assumed this one would work: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504972(v=vs.108).aspx ... but it has an additional object at the end (html attributes). By the way: one general question: why doesn't MSDN show the parameter names on listing.. I have to click at each overload to see names... is it possible to get all the parameter names listed somewhere without clicking?